# Loop through an object by not using two for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to loop through an object and get the values of the properties using two for loops.

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

let carTitles=[];
for (title of fakeData.cars)
  carTitles.push(title);

for (key of fakeData.usedCars) 
  carTitles.push(key);

console.log('cars as string are:', carTitles.join(','));
```

I get the output as expected, but was wondering if there is a better way to do this which would prevent using two for loops. Any suggestions? (thanks for the help earlier @cybercoder)

Comment: you could concat them *before* you loop

Comment: `let combinedCars = `${fakeData.cars} + ${fakeData.usedCars}` `?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by concatenating the arrays and using map:

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

const carTitles = [...fakeData.cars, ...fakeData.usedCars].map(car => car.title);

console.log('cars as string are:', carTitles.join(','));
```

If you want to keep the `for ... of` loop, you can also write it like this:

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

const allCars = [...fakeData.cars, ...fakeData.usedCars];
const carTitles = [];

for (let car of allCars) {
   carTitles.push(car.title);
}

console.log('cars as string are:', carTitles.join(','));
```

Comment: Not sure who did that, but what would be the difference between just declaring it as `const carTitles = [...fakeData.cars, ...fakeData.usedCars]` and looping through `carTitles` like `for (key of carTitles) { emptyArray.push(key.title) }` ? Or is it one and the same as yours?

Comment: It's basically the same. It's just a more compact way of writing it. On a technical level there is a difference (as how it's processed under the hood) but it's negligable. Though, you'd have to seperate it in 2 variables - I will add that to my answer for clarification :)